# Track movement of object from area to area in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, select

I have a very large SQL Server table that looks something like this:

```
TimeStamp                   Area         Type
---------------------------------------------
2018-07-17 07:23:00 AM      area1         0
2018-07-17 07:23:00 AM      area2         0
2018-07-17 07:23:00 AM      area3         1
2018-07-17 07:23:00 AM      area4         0
2018-07-17 07:23:15 AM      area1         0
2018-07-17 07:23:15 AM      area2         0
2018-07-17 07:23:15 AM      area3         0
2018-07-17 07:23:15 AM      area4         0
2018-07-17 07:23:30 AM      area1         0
2018-07-17 07:23:30 AM      area2         1
2018-07-17 07:23:30 AM      area3         0
2018-07-17 07:23:30 AM      area4         0
2018-07-17 07:23:45 AM      area1         0
2018-07-17 07:23:45 AM      area2         1
2018-07-17 07:23:45 AM      area3         0
2018-07-17 07:23:45 AM      area4         0
2018-07-17 07:24:00 AM      area1         0
2018-07-17 07:24:00 AM      area2         0
2018-07-17 07:24:00 AM      area3         0
2018-07-17 07:24:00 AM      area4         1
```

The Type column values:

- 1-> object is inside the area
- 0-> object is outside the area

Is there a type of select that creates time intervals (StartTime and EndTime) for each area where the type was 1 then 0 and so on?
Desired OUTPUT:

```
    StartTime               EndTime                     Area         Type
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
2018-07-17 07:23:00 AM      2018-07-17 07:24:00 AM      area1         0
2018-07-17 07:23:00 AM      2018-07-17 07:23:15 AM      area2         0
2018-07-17 07:23:30 AM      2018-07-17 07:23:45 AM      area2         1
2018-07-17 07:24:00 AM      2018-07-17 07:24:00 AM      area2         0
2018-07-17 07:23:00 AM      2018-07-17 07:23:00 AM      area3         1
2018-07-17 07:23:15 AM      2018-07-17 07:24:00 AM      area3         0
2018-07-17 07:23:00 AM      2018-07-17 07:23:45 AM      area4         0
2018-07-17 07:24:00 AM      2018-07-17 07:24:00 AM      area4         1
```

Comment: Why would all 4 rows of `07:23:00 AM` appear in your desired results?

Comment: The first 4 rows shows you were the object is at the begining (in wich area), before  it starts to move. My current approach uses fetch, but it s verry time consuming. It doesn t have to be that way exactly. I am opened to suggestions :).

Comment: I found the answear here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51876322/avoiding-fetch-in-sql-server-procedure